# Is it possible to disable hints?

Tags: neon-white

Neon White is all about trying to beat levels as fast as possible, and part of that fun is discovering the fastest route. However, after getting unlocking Insight 2 the game starts showing you hints on how to complete every level. That's great and all, but I'd rather figure out the routes myself, and only rely on the hints if/when I feel I need them.

I checked in the options menu and couldn't find anyway to turn hints off, although I could be missing something.

**Is it possible to disable hints in Neon White?**

Comment: I honestly have no idea how I managed to overlook this option until I was almost done the first "world", but I'm posting this in case anyone else is as thickheaded as me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.** You can disable hints before and after a level, on the level summary screen. It's located  in the bottom left section, under where your Insight is shown. Just check off the **Show Hints** option and hints will be disabled on all levels until you reenable them.

[image: neon white level complete]